# RDLC #Error driving me nuts (per page subtotals)

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, rdlc

I've got a report with a table looking like this:

```
UserCode|RecordID|OriginatingBranch|OriginatingAccount|HomingBranch|HomingAccount|Amount|ActionDate|SeqNo|Onus|Homedback
```

The last two columns are booleans, they contain either Y or N. In fact, the Onus column will only contain Ys. I need to have a subtotal at the end of each page showing how many Onus transactions there are and their value, and the same for Onus transactions.

I've tried several things including everything described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2011/06/06/transfooter-and-transheader-functionality-in-rdlc-ssrs-reports-revisited.aspx) but when I try that I'm left with a nondescript `#Error` in my report. I have no errors or logs or anything, just an `#Error` where I should have a number.

Now I'm trying the answer from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1e46ee76-bcb5-4541-9627-6fef5ebef060/how-to-have-subtotals-of-each-page-in-rdlc-), which says:

> 1. Add additional column and enter this expression: =Runningvalue(Fields!YourValue.Value,Sum,"yourtable1"), and set its hidden property to true.
> 2. In the page header or footer, use the expression: =Last(ReportItems!textbox12.Value) to get the subtotal of all previous pages.( assume that the above column’s detail row is textbox12)

I've put this in my table, this is my expression:

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!HomedBack.Value="Y", Fields!Amount2.Value, 0),Sum,"Items")
//my tablix is called "Items" and my "Amount" field is a formatted string, 
//the actual value is kept in "Amount2"
```

And lo and behold, I am getting the famous `#Error` again. My first row contains 0, and every row after that contains `#Error`.

I should note that I'm not viewing the report in a browser or interactively or anything like that, I'm using my company's old reporting library that is terrible and needs to be rewritten (I wish), and pretty much it takes a dataset and an RDLC and spits it out into a PDF.

Is there anything glaringly obvious that is wrong with my expression? I'm pretty new to RDLC so I feel like I'm missing something silly. Also is there any way to show exactly what these `#Error`s actually mean or correspond to?

Another note, I designed my RDLC in VS2013 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS can give `#Error` because of **data type mismatch**. It might be evaluating Amount2 as string field instead of numeric. To avoid such conditions do the **explicit conversion**.

Try this:

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!HomedBack.Value="Y", Fields!Amount2.Value*1.0, 0.0),Sum,"Items")
```

OR

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!HomedBack.Value="Y", CDBL(Fields!Amount2.Value), 0.0),Sum,"Items")
```

OR

```
=RunningValue(IIF(Fields!HomedBack.Value="Y", CDEC(Fields!Amount2.Value), 0),Sum,"Items")
```

Comment: I tried using CLNG and got the same issue, but thanks for the reply. I'll give CDBL and CDEC a try as well.